# Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView

Tags: c#-3.0

can someone explain me how the methode Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fov, aspect, nearClip, farClip);  is defined in XNA --> i mean  the matrix behind it !

thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming w, and h of:

```
h = cot(fieldOfViewY/2)
w = h * aspectRatio
```

This uses the following matrix:

```
w       0       0                                              0
0       h       0                                              0
0       0       farClip/(nearClip-farClip)                    -1
0       0       nearClip*farClip/(nearClip-farClip)            0
```

This isn't documented in the XNA docs, but is in the [DX documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb281728(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Hey Reed !

first of all thanks you a lot for your answer !  i will give it a try and let you know if it works ! take care